# Twisted adbapi fetchone

Tags: twisted

If I use runInteraction of Twisted's adbapi, and within the function that I call I do something like

```
curs. execute("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE name='bob'")
id = curs.fetchone()[0]
```

Am I guaranteed the id from this select or could it be from one of the other deferred threads?

Answer (score 0):

Deferreds are thread-safe so you can get guarantee.

Example code lookslike:

```
def _getAge(txn, user):
    # this will run in a thread, we can use blocking calls
    txn.execute("SELECT * FROM foo")
    # ... other cursor commands called on txn ...
    txn.execute("SELECT age FROM users WHERE name = ?", user)
    result = txn.fetchall()
    if result:
        return result[0][0]
    else:
        return None

def getAge(user):
    return dbpool.runInteraction(_getAge, user)

def printResult(age):
    if age != None:
        print age, "years old"
    else:
        print "No such user"

getAge("joe").addCallback(printResult)
```

This from official [docs](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/rdbms.html). I didn't remove any row to more clear and teaching.